# Why these two queries give different results?

Tags: mysql, sql

First query:

```
select count(*) from partner_goods_category p1 where p1.partner_id = 180 and not exists 
(select 1 from partner_goods_category p2 where 
    #p1.partner_id = 180 and 
    #p2.partner_id = 180 and 
    p1.partner_id = p2.partner_id and
    p2.parent_category_id = p1.category_id);

#1067
```

Second query:

```
select count(*) from partner_goods_category p1 where not exists 
(select 1 from partner_goods_category p2 where 
    #p1.partner_id = 180 and 
    p2.partner_id = 180 and 
    p1.partner_id = p2.partner_id and
    p2.parent_category_id = p1.category_id);


#1956
```

The second one seems to give wrong results. Why is that and what's the difference between those two queries? Because they logically seem identically to me (probably they work a bit different, but they should produce the same result). Database is MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Can you provide some data? (Fiddle will be great)

Comment: I don't really know specifics to `mysql` but in the first it references `p1.partner_id = 180` whereas in the second there is an extra hash `#` i.e. `#p1.partner_id = 180`

Answer (score 1):

First query has "where p1.partner_id = 180" additional where clause. So the second one check in every single record, but the first one only where partner_id is equal to 180.